# Saying letters?

Tags: dialogue, rules

How do you write dialogue in which the character is saying a letter?

Ex: “They speak a language pretty similar to english, just the letter **y** is replaced with double **e**s.”

Bolded letters are where the character is saying a letter is what I'm wondering about. Do I just do nothing, or is there something I need to do?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple ways to do this. One is to just write the letter (possibly with quotation marks or italics):

> They speak a language pretty similar to English, just the letter y is replaced with double e’s.

(it's worth noting that single letters are one of the rare cases in English where ‘s is used to mark the plural).

The other option is to spell out the letter names

> > They speak a language pretty similar to English, just the letter wye is replaced with double ees.

For your example, I would lean towards the first option, but there are other cases where spelling out makes sense (“he sometimes slipped with his accent and forgot to drop his aitches”). As long as you're consistent, you will be fine.